# Passing hardcoded template select field value to django model in parallel with modelform fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a contact model class and its respective modelForm:

```
# models.py

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=256, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.email

  # forms.py

class ContactForm(forms.modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'message',)
```

I have a respective views.py and template from where I am successfully submitting and saving the form data in my Contact model.

```
# views.py

def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

            email_subject = f'New contact {form.cleaned_data["email_address"]}: {form.cleaned_data["name"]}'
            email_message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            send_mail(email_subject, email_message, settings.CONTACT_EMAIL, settings.ADMIN_EMAIL)
        return redirect('home')

    form = ContactForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'web_page/contact_page.html', context)
```

However, as my subject field is hardcoded and consists of many values from html select tag with name="subject" and few dozens of options, I want to post it together with my modelForm fileds and save respective value in my Contact table. Is this possible anyway? I just want to avoid bringing all this existing records in forms.py as a CHOICE of my subject field.

I am on learning curve so forgive me if I am asking something stupid on top of I know already should work...

Comment: Can you please share your template? One option is to directly set choices in `name` field of `Contact` model itself.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but this is something I want to avoid i.e. having this long lists in modelForm or model class itself.